# Echo/ select only one value of multiple values in a row (cell)

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Is there a way to only select/echo only one value from a column that contains a list of values in each row?

For example, how can I select just `www.google.de` from:

```
SQL Rows:

id  link
-----------------------
1   www.google.de, www.facebook.com, www.stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: fetch all the data and then split it based on `,`

Comment: You mean like selecting only the `id` ?

Comment: Your question is not clear on what you want to have for results. Please show an example of your expected results.

Comment: you need to learn php mysql

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated items! It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: no i mean that i select one link like www.google.de and than echo the link as "a href"

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,group_concat(link) from table_name
group by id
```